# problem connection mongexpress to mongo db in kuberenetes

Tags: kubernetes

reference:
https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker_Kubernetes_MongoDB_MongoExpress.php

created few yamls files to understand the connection between multiple containers in kubernetes.
Mongoexpress can't connect to mongo db.

Getting the following error

> Could not connect to database using connectionString:
> mongodb://username:password@mongodbservice:27017/" (node:7)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect
> to server [mongodbservice:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo
> EAI_AGAIN mongodbservice
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {   name: 'MongoNetworkError'

```
        /*** mongodb deployment**/

        apiVersion: apps/v1
        kind: Deployment
        metadata:
          name: mongodb-deployment
          labels:
            app: mongo
        spec:
          replicas: 1
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              app: mongo
          template:
            metadata:
              labels:
                app: mongo
            spec:
              containers:
              - name: mongo
                image: mongo
                ports:
                - containerPort: 27017
                env:
                - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: secret-mongodb
                      key: userName
                - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
                  valueFrom: 
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: secret-mongodb
                      key: password
        ---
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Service
        metadata:
          name: mongodbservice
        spec:
          selector:
            app: mongo
          ports:
            - protocol: TCP
              port: 27017
              targetPort: 27017

    /************configmap**************/
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: mongodbconfigmap
    data:
      databaseurl: mongodbservice

    /*****************mongoexpress deployment******/
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: mongoexpress-deployment
      labels:
        app: mongoexpress
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mongoexpress
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: mongoexpress
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: mongoexpress
            image: mongo-express
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
            env:
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secret-mongodb
                  key: userName
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
              valueFrom: 
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secret-mongodb
                  key: password
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
              valueFrom: 
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongodbconfigmap
                  key: databaseurl
    ---

    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: mongoexpressservice
    spec:
      selector:
       app: mongoexpress
      type: LoadBalancer
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 8081
          targetPort: 8081
          nodePort: 30000
```

Comment: Is your mongo db up and running as part of mongodb deployment?

Comment: yes its running

Comment: i tried the same steps in minikube and i was able to view the mongo express UI without any issues.

Comment: okay , I am trying with dockerdesktop with kubernetes enabled, is there difference?

Comment: No there shouldn't be.